# twitter oauth - Invalid or expired token

Tags: codeigniter, twitter, twitter-oauth

I was using simon's twitter library to implement sign in with twitter in code igniter

here's the code

Twitter Configuration

```
$config['twitter'] = array(
'_tokens' => array(
    'consumer_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'consumer_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    //'access_key' => '',
    //'access_secret' => '',
),
'_force_login' => false, /* Do we force the user to login */
'_token_session' => 'twitter_oauth_tokens', /* Session name */
'_open_in_new_window' => true, /* Do links in Tweets get opened in a new window (add target="_blank" if true) */
'_new_window_target' => '_blank',
'_search_url' => 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%search%', /* Link for searches - '%search% is where the search key lives */
'_user_url' => 'http://twitter.com/%user%', /* Link for profiles - %user% is where the username lives */

/* Cache method (remember to make /applications/cache writable) or false for no caching */
'_cache_method' => array(
    'adapter' => 'apc',
    'backup' => 'file',
),
'cache_timeout' => 60, /* Timeout in seconds */

/* Most of these things shouldn't change */
'_access_token_url' => 'http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
'_api_url' => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/',
'_authorization_url' => 'http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
'_request_token_url' => 'http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
'_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
'_version' => '1.0',
'_method' => 'json',
);
```

Authorize twitter login

```
public function index() {

    /* Check we're logged in */
    if($this->twitter->is_logged_in()) {
        /* We are */
        //$test = $this->twitter->get_username();
        //var_dump($test);
        //$url = 'account/verify_credentials';


        //$arrData = $this->twitter->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');

        $user = $this->twitter->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');
        var_dump($user); }
```

but I get the following error as result

> 401 | Request failed{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid or expired token","code":89}]}

how to solve this problem?
any help would be appreaciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you resolve this problem?
Resetting your consumer key/secret in Twitter App settings, or 
Recreating your access token could help

Also check [Twitter OAuth - Invalid/Expired Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470854/twitter-oauth-invalid-expired-token)